# In Django Admin, how to allow a field to be writeable when the object is being created, but only readable after that?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I've made multiple attempts to achieve my objective.

When **adding** an object, I want the "value" field to be **writeable**.

When **changing** the object, I want it to be **readable**, like so :

[image]

So far, I've achieved two different solutions that **don't actually work**. The first one is to override the widgets with a `disabled` attribute :

```
@admin.register(MyObject)
class MyObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            # object exists, so this is a change form
            kwargs['widgets'] = {
                'value': forms.TextInput(attrs={'disabled': True, }),
            }
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

At first glance, this seems to work :
[image]

However, if I try to save my changes to the object, Django will return an error saying that the fields are required, as the `disabled` fields can't be saved.

The other option I've found is to alter the fields in get_form :

```
@admin.register(Batch)
class BatchAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        if obj:
            # object exists, this is a change form
            kwargs['fields'] = ['name',]
        else:
            # object does not exist yet, this is an add form
            kwargs['fields'] = ['name', 'value',]
        return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

This correctly gives me the ability to write the `value` field when adding an object, **but it hides the `value` field** altogether in the change form.

**How can I make a field writeable when added, and read-only when changed ?**

Comment: Use [`get_readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields).

Comment: Oh perfect thank you ! I hadn't thought of overwriting that !